# Android app with libgdx component

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx

I am looking for the best way to develop an Android app that has one component that allows the user to draw shapes, rotate them, scale them, slice them etc. (I am calling this component ActivityArea). In addition to this ActivityArea there need to be regular buttons, textViews, editViews etc. on the app.

I have explored 2 options - using libgdx and building a custom view. Both approaches appear doable. However, with libgdx, as far as I understand, all the buttons, textViews etc will also have to be created using the libgdx libraries. With this regard I have the following questions:

1. Is my understanding that libgdx will necessarily have to be used to render buttons and other regular android views?
2. Is there any way of including a libgdx powered view within an android layout?
3. Are there other libraries/options available that can be used to get geometric functions within an Android app?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Android UI atop LibGDX if you like. Typically for this you'd use the `AndroidApplication.initializeForView(...)` method to create the libgdx view and inject it into your layout.

As far as other libraries, if you doing 2d shapes and don't have to have a consistent 60fps, I'd probably just use Android's Canvas.